# Regex somente na palavra sem antecessor ou sucessor de pontos ou barras

Tags: python, regex

Gostaria de pegar o resultado da ocorrência sem sucessor ou antecessor de pontos ou barra, tenho meus casos no banco de dados:

```
Registro 1: VERSION01/VERSION01.5/VERSION01.5.5
Registro 2: VERSION01.5.5.5/VERSION02/VERSION02.5
```

Quando eu fosse usar a expressão regular para procurar **VERSION01.5**, encontrar apenas no Registro 1 a ocorrência dele em *VERSION01/**VERSION01.5**/VERSION01.5.5*, seria possível?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa é:

```
(?<![\w.])VERSION01\.5(?![\w.])
```

A regex usa [*lookbehind* e *lookahead* negativos](https://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), para verificar se algo **não** existe antes e depois.

Ambos possuem a expressão `[\w.]`, que é uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) que contém um `\w` (um [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) que contempla letras, números ou o caractere `_`) e o caractere `.`. Ou seja, esta expressão pega tanto uma letra/número/`_` quanto o ponto.

Esta expressão está dentro do *lookbehind* e *lookahead* negativos, indicando que não deve ter isso antes nem depois:

- `(?<![\w.])`: *lookbehind* negativo, verifica se antes **não** tem um ponto ou `\w`
- `(?![\w.])`: *lookahead* negativo, verifica se depois **não** tem um ponto ou `\w`

Ou seja, a regex verifica se "VERSION01.5" não tem letras, números, `_` ou ponto, nem antes nem depois.

Outro detalhe é que o ponto em "VERSION01.5" deve ser escapado com `\`, já que o ponto tem significado especial em regex (significa ["qualquer caractere, exceto quebras de linha"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)). Curiosamente, dentro dos colchetes ele não precisa do escape, pois ali ele já é interpretado como apenas o caractere `.`.

Enfim, ficaria assim:

```
textos =  [
  'Registro 1: VERSION01/VERSION01.5/VERSION01.5.5',
  'Registro 2: VERSION01.5.5.5/VERSION02/VERSION02.5',
  'Registro 3: VERSION01.5/VERSION02/VERSION02.5',
  'Registro 4: VERSION01.5.5.5/VERSION01.50/VERSION01.5'
]

import re

r = re.compile(r'(?<![\w.])VERSION01\.5(?![\w.])')
for texto in textos:
    if r.search(texto):
        print(f'encontrado: {texto}')
```

Saída:

```
encontrado: Registro 1: VERSION01/VERSION01.5/VERSION01.5.5
encontrado: Registro 3: VERSION01.5/VERSION02/VERSION02.5
encontrado: Registro 4: VERSION01.5.5.5/VERSION01.50/VERSION01.5
```

---

Se bem que neste caso você também pode fazer um [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.split):

```
r = re.compile(r'[ :/]')
for texto in textos:
    for s in r.split(texto):
        if s == 'VERSION01.5':
            print(f'encontrado: {texto}')
            break
```

A ideia é separar o texto em partes, usando como separador a regex `[ :/]` (um espaço, ou `:`, ou `/`). Aí é só verificar se alguma das partes é a versão que você quer - afinal, [*split* e *match* são apenas dois lados da mesma moeda](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#splitvsmatch): no *split* você diz o que não quer (no caso, o espaço, `:` ou `/`) e no *match* você diz o que quer ("VERSION01.5", sem nenhuma letra, dígito ou ponto antes e depois).

A saída é a mesma do código anterior.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente, irei ver a respeito se uso essa forma de procura e economizar idas ao banco. Valeu pelas fontes de estudo também, vou dá uma conferida.